# fetch onetomany by date

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently I'm facing with the following problem,

**What I want**

I want to receive a collection of timeslots where the date is only today or higher.

**My current entity class**

```
Class doctor     
@OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
///////////WHERE startdate >= DATETIME.now() equivalent \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
private Set<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new HashSet<>();
```

In my doctor class I have some timeslots. A timeslot has a startdate and enddate which I want to filter to skip past timeslots in the database. I only don't know how to fix this.

**What I tried**

I tried to use a filter which gave me the whole list back. Also I tried to use a where clause but wont work because of a need for a fixed number or date.

**My Question**

How do you fix this kind of problems in this situation. The only thing I want in jpa is adding a where clause to the entity class which is in pseudo code:

```
WHERE startdate < DATETIME.now()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate annotation [@Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where) to filter underlining collections:

```
@OneToMany(...)
@Where("startdate >= now()")
private Set<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new HashSet<>();
```

Note that parameter of this annotation is native sql (`now()` is MySQL specific function).